# why Java code and Python code generate different signature of encode_jwt

Tags: python, java, algorithm, jwt

#1. python code:

```
payload = {"login_user_key": "b7c5443c-5395-46b0-b6c1-d940fd686880"}
secret = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
headers = {"alg": "HS512", "typ": "JWT"}
encoded_jwt = jwt.encode(payload, secret, algorithm='HS512', headers=headers)
print(encoded_jwt)
```

#result:eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJsb2dpbl91c2VyX2tleSI6ImI3YzU0NDNjLTUzOTUtNDZiMC1iNmMxLWQ5NDBmZDY4Njg4MCJ9.fmhdCmM4BJBOASK_UXtRoszP0Q614mDlQ3iDU9_ZFCr--jh--OHG8o5aCG4Zgpcpmsry9NH1LY-4Bd_NN0mmQQ

//2. java code:

```
        String secret = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
        claims.put("login_user_key", "b7c5443c-5395-46b0-b6c1-d940fd686880");
        String jwttoken = Jwts.builder()
                .setHeaderParam("alg", "HS512")
                .setHeaderParam("typ", "JWT")
                .setClaims(claims)
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, secret).compact();
        System.out.println(jwttoken);
```

//result:eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJsb2dpbl91c2VyX2tleSI6ImI3YzU0NDNjLTUzOTUtNDZiMC1iNmMxLWQ5NDBmZDY4Njg4MCJ9.Gat6BTTXtwC_XWN4pZjqC-x4Bw24xfpNXmLIMSysa3FJaPvpnXcjO0wp6FBlKtrfYyqZRQARQbE4rGwhAOY_eg

please tell me that Java code and Python code generate different signature of encode_jwt ,and modify the python code to make the final generated jwt the same. please....

I tried to use chatgpt to give an answer, but it didn't work, it may not be a problem with key encoding, maybe a problem with json data or string data?

Comment: `secret = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';` isn't valid Java.

Comment: There are some more details at this [web about JSON web tokens in python](https://elc.github.io/python-security/chapters/10_JSON_Web_Tokens.html). However, my best shot would be that the encoding for those characters would be different in Python/Java, thus generating different results. I'm not native to either language, so idk exactly how they behave.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes i see what you mean, i just wanted to express that the result is different when the key is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the API docs:

- [`jwt.encode(payload, key, algorithm="HS256", headers=None, json_encoder=None)`](https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=jwt#jwt.encode) (Python)
- [`JwtBuilder.signWith(SignatureAlgorithm alg, String base64EncodedSecretKey)`](https://javadoc.io/static/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt-api/0.11.5/io/jsonwebtoken/JwtBuilder.html#signWith(io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm,%20java.lang.String)) (Java)

I'm speculating you need to be using:

- [`JwtBuilder.signWith(SignatureAlgorithm alg, byte[] secretKey)`](https://javadoc.io/static/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt-api/0.11.5/io/jsonwebtoken/JwtBuilder.html#signWith(io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm,%20byte%5B%5D)) (Java)

```java
    String secret = "..."; // The same as with Python
    ...
    String jwttoken = Jwts.builder()
            ...
            .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, secret.getBytes())
            .compact();
```

Alternatively, if your Java result is already as intended, you might need to change the Python code like:

```py
import base64
...
encoded_jwt = jwt.encode(payload, base64.b64decode(secret), algorithm='HS512', headers=headers)
```

*Disclaimer:* I don't have any Python experience.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, let me understand that this is indeed a key character encoding problem. After adding the secret.getBytes() code to the java code, the same key is really generated, but I still don't understand how to modify the python code to achieve , sorry I'm just a beginner.